# w3schools xsd example won't work with dom4j. How do I use dom4j to validate xml using xsds?

Tags: java, xsd, dom4j

I am trying to use dom4j to validate the xml at http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_example.asp using the xsd from that same page. It fails with the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'shiporder'.
```

I'm using the following code:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
reader.setValidation(true);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
reader.setErrorHandler(new XmlErrorHandler());
reader.read(in);
```

where in is an InputStream and XmlErrorHandler is a simple class that just logs all errors.

I'm using the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test1.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

and the corresponding xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:simpleType name="stringtype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="inttype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="dectype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="orderidtype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{6}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="shiptotype">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="stringtype"/>
    <xs:element name="address" type="stringtype"/>
    <xs:element name="city" type="stringtype"/>
    <xs:element name="country" type="stringtype"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="itemtype">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="title" type="stringtype"/>
    <xs:element name="note" type="stringtype" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="quantity" type="inttype"/>
    <xs:element name="price" type="dectype"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="shipordertype">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="orderperson" type="stringtype"/>
    <xs:element name="shipto" type="shiptotype"/>
    <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="itemtype"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="orderidtype" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="shiporder" type="shipordertype"/>

</xs:schema>
```

The xsd and xml file are in the same directory. What is the problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong.
How are you building your input stream for reader.read(in);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because of this:

```
reader.read(in);
```

You're not giving the reader any context as to where the input stream is coming from, so it cannot resolve the schema. Try passing the reader something like a `File` or `URL`  object instead, something it can use to generate a relative reference to the schema.